# Understanding Typescript Record type with React's useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm having some issues understanding the record type in a generator function I'm developing for React contexts.

Here's my generator function:

```
import * as React from 'react'

export type State = Record<string, unknown>
export type Action = { type: string; payload?: unknown }

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
export type Actions = Record<string, Function>


export type AppContext = { state: State; actions: Actions }
export type Reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => State

type ProviderProps = Record<string, unknown>
type FullContext = {
    Context: React.Context<AppContext>
    Provider: React.FC<ProviderProps>
}

/**
 * Automates context creation
 *
 * @param {Reducer} reducer
 * @param {Actions} actions
 * @param {State} initialState
 * @returns {Contex, Provider}
 */
export default (
    reducer: Reducer,
    actions: Actions,
    initialState: State,
    init: () => State = (): State => initialState,
): FullContext => {
    const Context = React.createContext<AppContext>({
        state: { ...initialState },
        actions,
    })

    const Provider = ({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState, init)

        const boundActions: Actions = {}
        for (const key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)
        }

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{ state, actions: { ...boundActions } }}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }

    return {
        Context,
        Provider,
    }
}
```

The core of the issue is here:

```
        const boundActions: Actions = {}
        for (const key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)
        }
```

What I'm trying to do is to have a function I can call with a reducer and inital state to generate a Context provider that I can use anywhere in the app. In this case, I'm attempting to generate an `AuthContext`. This context will take a reducer that looks like this:

```
const authReducer: Reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'login':
            return { ...state, isLogged: true, avoidLogin: false }
        case 'logout':
            return { ...state, isLogged: false, avoidLogin: true }
        default:
            return { ...state }
    }
}
```

Quite barebones, but it basically changes some booleans in an object.

Now, this code actually works but what bugs me is the use of the Function type in the declaration of the Actions type.

`export type Actions = Record<string, Function>`

using `unknown` also works, but now typescript complains that `Object is of type 'unknown'.` when doing: `boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)`, specifically on `actions[key]`, because I'm calling it as a function.

Actions are functions that take in a function (dispatch) as an argument and return a `State` object.

Here's my actions declaration to further illustrate:

```
const actions: Actions = {
    login: (dispatch: (action: Action) => void) => () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'login' })
    },
    logout: (dispatch: (action: Action) => void) => () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'logout' })
    },
}
```

If I console log `boundActions` in my generator I get something like:

```
Object {
  "login": [Function anonymous],
  "logout": [Function anonymous],
}
```

This is precisely what I want as I want to be able to call these functions anywhere in my code and this will, in turn, call the dispatch function of a specific reducer changing the state of a specific context.

Now, I'm fairly new with Typescript, but my gut tells me the declaration of the `Actions` type should be something like:

`export type Actions = Record<string, (dispatch:Function) => State>`

The problem with this is:
1- it doesn't work because now `boundActions` say something like:

```
Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type '(dispatch: Function) => Record<string, unknown>'.
  Type 'Record<string, unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(dispatch: Function): Record<string, unknown>'.
```

2- I'm still using the Function type which isn't typesafe.

Now, `dispatch` takes a an action as parameter `export type Action = { type: string; payload?: unknown }`

So my guess would be `export type Actions = Record<string, (dispatch(arg:Action)) => State>`

but this doesn't work either because it's not valid typescript code.

I know this case is kind of unnecessarily complicated, but I just want to better understand the use of Record in this specific case, where a record has `string` keys and `Function` values.

At the end of the day, all I want is to do something like:

```
export default function Login(): JSX.Element {
    const {
        actions: { login },
    } = React.useContext(AuthContext)

    return (
        <View>
            <Button text='Entrar' onPress={() => login()} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

Which actually works, but it is not typesafe.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with actions that accept different arguments the action creator then you want to define your types based on a map of those specific actions rather than on a vague generalized type.

Since you only have two action creators here both of them don't take any arguments (other than dispatch) then they can both be described by the following type:

```
(dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>) => () => void
```

So you would have

```
type Actions = Record<string, (dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>) => () => void>
```

I still don't like this type because it has `string` as the key type instead of your specific action functions `login` and `logout`.  But now that we've typed it better Typescript can start working as intended and giving us helpful errors.

The `boundActions` that you create in your function should not have the same type as the `actions` that we pass as an argument.  The `actions` are functions which take `Dispatch` and return a function `() => void`.  The `boundActions` are just the returned function `() => void`.

So we're starting to see some problems with your design.  It doesn't make sense (or pass type checks) to use unbound actions as a default value for the context, as these are inherently different than their bound versions.

Those errors were hidden when you were just using `Function` as a type, which is precisely why it is dangerous!

You can create solid types for your `AuthContext` without doing anything "fancy".  But you want to create a factory that supports creating multiple different contexts.  You can use lots of vague types like `Record` and `any` and you won't have any typescript errors, but you also won't get much helpful information when you go to *use* the context.  What properties are on the `state`?  What actions can I call? If you want to create a factory that has knowledge about the specific context that it is creating then you need to use more advanced Typescript features like generics and mapped types.

Generic Setup

```
import React, { Reducer, Dispatch as _Dispatch } from 'react';

// Very generalized action type
export type Action = { type: string; payload?: any }

// We are not using specific action types.  So we override the React Dispatch type with one that's not generic
export type Dispatch = _Dispatch<Action>

// 

// Map from action functions of dispatch to their bound versions
type BoundActions<ActionMap> = {
    [K in keyof ActionMap]: ActionMap[K] extends ((dispatch: Dispatch) => infer A) ? A : never
}

// The type for the context depends on the State and the action creators
export type AppContext<State, ActionMap> = {
    state: State;
    actions: BoundActions<ActionMap>;
}

type FullContext<State, ActionMap> = {
    Context: React.Context<AppContext<State, ActionMap>>;
    Provider: React.FC; // Provider does not take any props -- just children
}

const createAuthContext = <
    // type for the state
    State,
    // type for the action map
    ActionMap extends Record<string, (dispatch: Dispatch) => (...args: any[]) => void>>(
        reducer: Reducer<State, Action>,
        actions: ActionMap,
        initialState: State,
        init: () => State = (): State => initialState,
): FullContext<State, ActionMap> => {
    const Context = React.createContext<AppContext<State, ActionMap>>({
        state: { ...initialState },
        actions: Object.fromEntries(
            Object.keys(actions).map(key => (
                [key, () => console.error("cannot call action outside of a context provider")]
            )
            )) as BoundActions<ActionMap>,
    })

    const Provider = ({ children }: { children?: React.ReactNode }) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState, init)

        // this is not the most elegant way to handle object mapping, but it always requires some assertion
        // there is already a bindActionCreators function in Redux that does this.
        const boundActions = {} as Record<string, any>
        for (const key in actions) {
            boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch)
        }

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={{ state, actions: boundActions as BoundActions<ActionMap> }}>
                {children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }

    return {
        Context,
        Provider,
    }
}
```

Specific Implementation

```
export type AuthState = {
    isLogged: boolean;
    avoidLogin: boolean;
}

const authReducer = (state: AuthState, action: Action): AuthState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'login':
            return { ...state, isLogged: true, avoidLogin: false }
        case 'logout':
            return { ...state, isLogged: false, avoidLogin: true }
        default:
            return { ...state }
    }
}

// no type = let it be inferred
const actions = {
    login: (dispatch: Dispatch) => () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'login' })
    },
    logout: (dispatch: Dispatch) => () => {
        dispatch({ type: 'logout' })
    },
}

const initialAuthState: AuthState = {
    isLogged: false,
    avoidLogin: true
}

const { Context: AuthContext, Provider } = createAuthContext(authReducer, actions, initialAuthState);

export function Login(): JSX.Element {
    // this is where the magic happens!
    const {
        // can only destructure known actions, will get errors on typos
        actions: { login },
        state
    } = React.useContext(AuthContext)

    // we now know all the properties of the state and their types
    const { isLogged } = state;

    return (
        <View>
            <Button text='Entrar' onPress={() => login()} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wRpGYm)

Answer (score 0):

I think this example is helpful to understand `Record` type in TS.

```
type AppProps = {
  /** a dictionary object with any number of properties of the same type */
  dict1: {
    [key: string]: MyTypeHere;
  };
  dict2: Record<string, MyTypeHere>; // equivalent to dict1
}
```